# Why does Javascript have substr() and substring()?

Tags: javascript, substring, substr

Where did `substr()` and `substring()` originate? Why are there two methods to do the same thing with slightly different behaviours?

No programmer in their right mind would create two methods with different behaviour where the only difference in the name is the one is an abbreviated version of the other, so how did this happen?

Comment: Ahh, OK, re-reading that I see what you're saying now :p - comment removed

Comment: @JaromandaX Haha all good :)